# Clearing Eclipse's output console with PyDev Remote Debugger(pydevd)?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have these 2 lines at the beginning of my script and remote debugging works very nicely:

```
from pysrc.pydevd import settrace
settrace('localhost', stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True, suspend=False)
```

My question is, is there a way to clear Eclipse's console every time `settrace` is called? 
I'm currently doing it manually, which gets a bit annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, there's no way to do that automatically.

What you could do however is calling settrace and right afterwards do something as:

```
print('\n'*40 + '*'*80)
```

so that you know that the debug session started at that point (then maybe you wouldn't need to clear it?)